# Can't target iframe with watir-webdriver - Bug?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am pretty new to automation and watir-webdriver so forgive me if I don't sound super techy.

I am trying to log in to a website and the login form is inside of an iframe. There is also another iframe on the same page that contains an image.

This is the html:

```
<body>
<div class="topbar">
<div class="topbarcenter">
<ul>
<li id="logo" class="logo">
<div id="provider_logo">
<iframe id="logo_iframe" width="192px" height="128px" frameborder="0" src="http://social.onerecovery.com/modules/iframes/html/provider_logo.html?prov=microsites" onload="this.style.visibility = "visible";" style="visibility: visible;" allowtransparency="true">
</div>
</li>
<li class="login">
<iframe id="login_iframe" width="550px" height="70px" frameborder="0" src="http://social.onerecovery.com/modules/iframes/html/login.html" onload="this.style.visibility = "visible";" style="visibility: visible;" allowtransparency="true">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="login_container">
<div id="login_div">
<form class="login_form" action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email Address..." class="email_input processed" name="email">
```

by the way I am using watir-webdriver 0.3.5 and automating on chrome 17

what I tried was:
`$b.frame(:id => "login_iframe").form(:class => "login_form").text_field(:name => "email").set("username")`

which I thought would work but in my command line I just get the error: `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:class=>"login_form", :tag_name=>"form"}`

I also tried indexing the iframe to make sure I was in the second iframe and not the first but it still didn't work.

When I do
`$b.frame(:id => "login_iframe").exists?` in command line, I get 
`true`

but when I do
`$b.frame(:id => "login_iframe").form(:class => "login_form").exists?` in command line, I get
`false`

The thing is that we have another page that someone can use to login to the same website and the only difference between that page and this page is that this page has a second iframe whereas the other page only has the login iframe and the code
`$b.frame(:id => "login_iframe").form(:class => "login_form").text_field(:name => "email").set("username")`
works perfectly fine.
Sorry for going on so long. Just wanted to make sure that I gave enough info. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Two questions. (1) Is the page you are testing publicly accessible? Your code works for me given your HTML sample, so I am wondering if it is a timing issue (ie you try to access the form before the iframe finishes loading). (2) Did you mean watir-webdriver 0.5.3 (latest) rather than 0.3.5?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. 1)The site is accessible at http://microsites.onerecovery.com I don't think its a timing issue because when I run code line by line in the command line I still can't target the form in the iframe. 2) I am using watir-webdriver 0.3.5 which is what I was using when I started automation and I haven't upgraded to the latest version yet. I really appreciate any insight you have into the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your original code works fine in Firefox, so I would assume it is a bug with the ChromeDriver.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it! I will get in contact with the right people to check into a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to solving your problem is to use `browser.frame(:index => 2)` instead of `browser.frame(:id => "login_iframe")`.

Or if you want a slightly more robust solution:

```
frame = browser.frames.find{ |frame| frame.form(:class => "login_form").exists? }
frame.form(:class => "login_form").text_field(:name => "email").set("username")
```

That said, I really do not know why that works. It is like it thinks the login control is inside the `invite_iframe`, which it does not look like in the HTML. I will try to dig deeper, but sounds like a bug to me.

It appears that all of the iframes are shuffled funny. As you can see by the following, the number of text fields in each iframe does not match what is expected.

```
browser.frames.each{ |x| puts x.id + ' - ' + x.text_fields.length.to_s + ' text_fields' }
#=> logo_iframe - 3 text_fields
#=> login_iframe - 0 text_fields
#=> invite_iframe - 2 text_fields
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I appreciate the help. I sent a message to Jari who is a Watir guy and asked him if he could look into it when he has the time. I think it is probably a bug too.

Comment: If it's a bug in chromedriver, you might need to update your version of chromedriver before you do anything else.  I'd also consider keeping your watir-webdriver up to date as well, there's been some nice new stuff appearing in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions, it is `browser.iframes` which lists all the iframes current window has.

```
browser.iframes.map {|iframe| iframe.src}
```

This will map `src` attributes of all iframes.